# Microsoft Excel - Search and find the next highest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not an Excel expert and I need some help.

I have a list of different numbers and a reference number. I have a formula where it gives me the closest value of my number from this list
Example:

10
11
16
20
30

My reference number is 13.

I have found online a formula that gives me the closest number which in this case is the number 11.

```
=INDEX(list;MATCH(MIN(ABS(list-reference_number));ABS(list-reference_number);0))
```

But I want the result to be 16 (the next highest number).

I would like to know if this is possible and how can I achieve it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure how your list of numbers relate to the formula - there's 5 numbers, but you reference 100 rows.  But, if you can resort your numbers into descending order you could use a formula like `=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(13,$A$1:$A$5,-1))`

Answer (score 2):

Since `MATCH(refernce,list)` will return the closest to 13. That means `MATCH(refernce,list)+1` will return the result you looking for:

[image]

Formula in to use:

```
=INDEX(C1:C5,MATCH(13,C1:C5)+1)
```

Comment: The list is an example and there are much more numbers in real list, in which the numbers change. So numbers are not absolute. I have an easiest explanation. If my reference number is 13, then the result must be not below 13. It has to be the next highest number in the list.

Comment: That's exactly what my proposed formula does. I'm not sure what else you are after. Maybe you more after: `=INDEX(C1:C5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C1:C5>13,),0))`

Comment: @JvdV apologies for reviving a slightly outdated topic! I think the formula is incorrect - note that if you change cell C3 (currently `16`) to something higher (e.g. `66`), then your formula will return `66`. I suspect OP would like to see the next highest value, which in such case would be `20`.

Comment: If the sequence of numbers indeed would not follow logically you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another Array formula for you to try (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(IF(A1:A5-B1>0,A1:A5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Provided column `A` contains the numbers, which can be unsortet by the way, you can get the closest higher number with:

```
{=MIN(IF($A:$A>B1,$A:$A,MAX($A:$A)+1))}
```

`B1` contains the reference number (in your case 13).

*Note: This is an [array formular](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7). You don't have to enter the curly braces. Instead paste the formular without `{` and `}` and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to confirm your input.*